# Screen backlight problem Ubuntu 13.04 Lenovo G700

Tags: 13.04, screen, lenovo, backlight

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Lenovo G700 Laptop.

1. Screen backlight is going off after boot.
2. I have tried to fix it with setting

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```

   in **/etc/default/grub** file - in that case backlight is set up to 100% and I am not able to change it.

I am looking for a solution when screen is not black after boot and I am able to change the backlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used following settings

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Backlight after boot is set to 100% and I am able to change it with System Settings or hardware keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

also make sure you run

```
sudo update-grub
```

before you reboot

Comment: Also use the FN keys to change brightness or set a key binding for it, because sliders still refuse to work even with a fix like this.

Comment: I have tried your solution. Screen backlight after boot is set to 100% lighten - I am able to change it with "System settings" but not with hardware keys.

Comment: That's as far as my knowledge with backlight fixes in grub goes, sorry, I wish I could help further.